X553 SFP+ (rev 11) working on Ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS but not on Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS
I have a system with X553 SFP+ slots interface(4 of em).
this system
When i install Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS the network device stay in a disconnected state.
When i install on the exact same machine(network cables untouched) Ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS the network works.
The interface is tagged with a vlan number by the switch.
The culprit seems to be the version of Ubuntu.
What data should i collect, where to share it(forum, mailing-list, irc, discord) for the developer to take a look at?
Below some output from ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS
root@s01:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series System Agent (rev 11)
00:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Error Registers (rev 11)
00:05.0 Generic system peripheral [0807]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Root Complex Event Collector (rev 11)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Integrated QAT Root Port (rev 11)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 11)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 11)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 11)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 11)
00:0e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev 11)
00:0f.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev 11)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev 11)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev 11)
00:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SMBus Contoller - Host (rev 11)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SATA Controller 0 (rev 11)
00:14.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SATA Controller 1 (rev 11)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Integrated LAN Root Port #0 (rev 11)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Integrated LAN Root Port #1 (rev 11)
00:18.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series ME HECI 1 (rev 11)
00:1a.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series HSUART Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series LPC or eSPI (rev 11)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Power Management Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SMBus controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SPI Controller (rev 11)
01:00.0 Co-processor: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series QuickAssist Technology (rev 11)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E12 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
09:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 03)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 10 GbE SFP+ (rev 11)
0b:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 10 GbE SFP+ (rev 11)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 10 GbE SFP+ (rev 11)
0c:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 10 GbE SFP+ (rev 11)

root@s01:~# ethtool -i eno3
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.15.0-124-generic
firmware-version: 0x80000c01
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:0c:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes

Please let me know if i can supply more information to get this network card working on ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS

Seems to be a driver issue, found this link
https://homenetworkguy.com/how-to/manually-install-x553-driver-in-linux-for-intel-atom-cpu/
https://lore.kernel.org/netdev/4a0bf7cf-d108-49ac-ac7c-6136a070c44b@intel.com/T/

First install the dependencies:
sudo apt install build-essential dkms gcc make

Download and extract the X553 driver. You may need to get a newer
version but at the time of this writing the driver below is the
latest version. You can find the ixgbe driver page on Intel's website.
wget https://downloadmirror.intel.com/825849/ixgbe-5.20.9.tar.gz
sudo tar xvfvz ixgbe-5.20.9.tar.gz -C /usr/src

Open a new file using nano:
sudo nano /usr/src/ixgbe-5.20.9/dkms.conf

Add the following lines to the file:
MAKE="BUILD_KERNEL=${kernelver} make -C src/ KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/${kernelver}/build"
CLEAN="make -C src/ clean"
PACKAGE_NAME="ixgbe-dkms"
PACKAGE_VERSION="5.20.9"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME="ixgbe"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION=src/
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION="/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"

Press Ctrl + O to save the file and Ctrl + X to exit the text editor.
Finally, run the command below to add, build, and install the Intel
X553 driver using dkms. By using dkms, the driver should automatically
recompile anything there is a new kernel update.
sudo dkms add ixgbe/5.20.9
sudo dkms build ixgbe/5.20.9
sudo dkms install ixgbe/5.20.9


